# combining patches to obtain single transparency in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I calculate ellipse-like polygons which are drawn over another image. The polygons together form one shape and must have a single transparency. Unfortunately, if I draw one polygon after another, the stack gets different transparencies. In the example below I have 3 polygons, creating 3 transparencies, resulting in different grey areas instead of one. Does anyone know how to obtain a single transparency?

Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon, Rectangle

def get_ellipse_coords(a=0.0, b=0.0, x=0.0, y=0.0, angle=0.0, k=2):

    pts = np.zeros((360*k+1, 2))
    beta = -angle * np.pi/180.0
    sin_beta = np.sin(beta)
    cos_beta = np.cos(beta)
    alpha = np.radians(np.r_[0.:360.:1j*(360*k+1)])

    sin_alpha = np.sin(alpha)
    cos_alpha = np.cos(alpha)

    pts[:, 0] = x + (a * cos_alpha * cos_beta - b * sin_alpha * sin_beta)
    pts[:, 1] = y + (a * cos_alpha * sin_beta + b * sin_alpha * cos_beta)

    return pts

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
    plt.xlim([-5,5])
    plt.ylim([-5,5])

    c='0.5'
    alp=0.5

    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((1.5, -4.0),0.5,8.0,
                           color='lightblue', zorder=1))

    pts = get_ellipse_coords(a=4.0, b=1.0)
    ax.add_patch(Polygon(pts, closed=True, lw=0.5,
                         color=c, alpha=alp,zorder=2))

    pts = get_ellipse_coords(a=4.0, b=1.0, x=1.0, angle=30)
    ax.add_patch(Polygon(pts, closed=True, lw=0.5,
                         color=c, alpha=alp, zorder=2))

    pts = get_ellipse_coords(a=2.0, b=0.25, x=2.0, y=-2.0, angle=250)
    ax.add_patch(Polygon(pts, closed=True, lw=0.5,
                         color=c, alpha=alp, zorder=2))

    plt.show()
```

np.concatenate, suggested in the first answer, does the trick I need:

```
    [...]
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle((1.5, -4.0),0.5,8.0,
                           color='lightblue', zorder=1))

    pts1 = get_ellipse_coords(a=4.0, b=1.0)
    pts2 = get_ellipse_coords(a=4.0, b=1.0, x=1.0, angle=30)
    pts3 = get_ellipse_coords(a=2.0, b=0.25, x=2.0, y=-2.0, angle=250)

    stoppoint = np.array([[np.nan,np.nan]])     
    pts = np.concatenate((pts1, stoppoint, pts2))
    pts = np.concatenate((pts, stoppoint, pts3))  

    ax.add_patch(Polygon(pts, closed=True, lw=0.0,
                         color=c, alpha=alp, zorder=2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
pts1 = get_ellipse_coords(a=4.0, b=1.0)
pts2 = get_ellipse_coords(a=4.0, b=1.0, x=1.0, angle=30)
stoppoint = np.array([[nan,nan]])     

pts = np.concatenate((pts1, stoppoint, pts2))

ax.add_patch(Polygon(pts, closed=True, lw=0.5,
                     color=c, alpha=alp,zorder=2))
```

The `stoppoint` prevents a line connecting the ellipses.

Comment: I do not understand it yet, but this seems to work. thank you!

Comment: It just combines the ellipses to a single object. Then the transparency is assign to the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution did not work for me, I had to build my compound path with [matplotlib.path.Path.make_compound_path_from_polys](https://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.make_compound_path_from_polys) and then pass its vertices to my [matplotlib.patches.Polygon](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html?highlight=polygon#matplotlib.patches.Polygon) class instance.

The gist of it as [documented](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/histogram_path.html) is as follows:

```python
data = np.random.randn(1000)
n, bins = np.histogram(data, 50)

# get the corners of the rectangles for the histogram
left = np.array(bins[:-1])
right = np.array(bins[1:])
bottom = np.zeros(len(left))
top = bottom + n

# we need a (numrects x numsides x 2) numpy array for the path helper
# function to build a compound path
XY = np.array([[left, left, right, right], [bottom, top, top, bottom]]).T

# get the Path object
barpath = path.Path.make_compound_path_from_polys(XY)

# make a patch out of it
patch = patches.PathPatch(barpath)
ax.add_patch(patch)
```